# Does a convergent series converge is are divided by $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $a_n \ge 0$ if the series converge $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 \lt \infty $$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} \lt \infty $$
also will diverge?

Comment: The second one will converge by Comparison.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo, why did you change the question from $a_n$ to $a_n^2$?

Comment: It is trivial if you remove the "square"....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just see this since $a_n>0$ by Schwartz inequality we have

> $$\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n} \leq \sqrt{\sum_n a^2_n} \sqrt{ \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}}< \infty.  $$

Note that the convergence of $\sum_n a_n $ implies the convergence of $\sum_n a^2_n $.

Comment: I like it....................+1

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{n\in N: a_n^2<a_n/n\}$ and $T=N\backslash S.$

We have $n\in S\implies a_n<1/n \implies a_n/n<1/n^2.$

We have $n\in T\implies a_n/n\leq a_n^2.$

So $\quad \sum_{n=1}^{n=M}a_n/n\leq \sum_{(M\geq n\in S)}1/n^2\;  +\; \sum_{(M\geq n\in T)}a_n^2.\quad$ Which is bounded above as $M\to \infty.$

(With the usual convention that the sum over an empty set is $0.$)

Comment: Or we could just say $a_n /n \leq \max (a_n^2,1/n^2) \leq a_n^2+1/n^2 $  for all $n.$